# Going to the USA on a reason different from what I said when getting a visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I recently acquired a B1/B2 visa for two years on grounds of attending an environment conference in California, however the conference will not take place as scheduled, So can I visit another state such as Colorado to visit someone?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. As long as your trip is genuine.

Comment: Please do not just answer with a few words without giving a link to an official site. Personal experience answers can be useful, one word ones are not. I do not vote to delete yet but likely others will. If you can edit you might safe the answer.